# How can I fix this to order a list in a vector

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void selecao(float A[], int n)
{
    int i, j, indicmin;
    float auxiliar;
for (i = 0; n-1; i++)
{
    indicmin = i;
    for(j = i+1 ; j< n; j++)
        if (A[j] < A[indicmin])
            indicmin = j;
        auxiliar = A[indicmin];
        A[indicmin] = A[i];
        A[i] = auxiliar;

    }
 }
 // Imprimir a lista em ordem crescente
void ImprimirLista (float a[], int n) 
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) 
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    cout << endl ;
}
 int main()
{
    float A[4]={1.0,4.0,3.0,0.0};
    selecao(A,4);
    ImprimirLista(A,4);
}
```

I nees this to form a list in crescent order, so to test I create the ImprimirLista and main, but the result is nothing. Don't print anything.

Comment: also `for (i = 0; n-1; i++)` is wrong, shouldn't it be `for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)`

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem, this was from a book, so I thought it was right, but the book have a lot mistakes

Comment: your second for loop has a missing opening bracket {

Answer (score 1):

```
using namespace std;
void selecao(float* A, int n)
{
    int i, j, indicmin;
    float auxiliar;
    for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++)
    {
        indicmin = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < A[indicmin])
                indicmin = j;
        }
        auxiliar = A[indicmin];
        A[indicmin] = A[i];
        A[i] = auxiliar;

    }
}
```

In main you need below change:

```
selecao(&A[0], 4);
```

Why your program was not working?
First for loop comparison was wrong as well as array passed wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the `stl`?

```
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    float v[4] {1.0f, 4.0f, 3.0f, 0.0f};
    std::sort(v,v+v_size);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use the code in the book, but thanks!

Comment: I have found that many tutors and books seem to be anti stl :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is a Selection Sort.
General form:

```
void selectSort(int* a, int n)
{
    int minIdx, minValue;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        minIdx = i;
        minValue = a[i];
        for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if(a[j] < minValue)
            {
                minIdx = j;
                minValue = a[j];
            }
        }
        if(minIdx != i)
        {
            int temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[minIdx];
            a[minIdx] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Your Code:

```
void selecao(float A[], int n)
{
    int i, j, indicmin;
    float min;
    float auxiliar;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        indicmin = i;
        min = A[i];
        for(j = i+1 ; j< n; j++)
        {
            if (A[j] < min)
            {
                indicmin = j;
                min = A[j];
            }
        }
        if(indicmin != i)
        {
            auxiliar = A[indicmin];
            A[indicmin] = A[i];
            A[i] = auxiliar;
        }
    }
 }
```